# 16.04 Desktop hangs after period of inactivity

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, crash

I have tried to search for the answer for this issue on many sites including this one with no luck. I have even checked [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) and did not help. It's not my intention to post a duplicate question, but to seek for the answer after trying many avenues to resolve the problem.

After period of inactivity, UI stops responding. When I checked various log files I could not find anything. Machine is alive in the sense, I can ssh to the box from different computer. However keyboard and mouse are completely dead. Even caps lock can not be turned on. I can not switch to terminal window and REISUB did not work for me - may be because keyboard is dead.

The box is not setup to suspend or hibernate. All service updates are up to date. When logged in via ssh command, I did not see any unusual activity nor was machine busy.

Few things I have noticed

- Started happening two weeks back. Before that never had a problem.
- May be it's coincidence, but box normally freezes when I have mysql
  workbench running and I step away from the desk for enough time to
  activate screen saver.
- No other problems on the box at all

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with a PC running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS that after leaving it for several minutes, screen would go dark (a little different from  your case), but the PC is not turned off, not suspend or hibernate, but I could not wake it up with the mouse or keyboard.  I needed to turn off / turn on the PC to solve this issue.  It seems that this issue has always been there since the PC was upgraded to 16.04.

I tried changing power settings, and updating kernel.  But these did not work.

What worked for me is I changed the System Settings->Brightness & Lock, and set the Turn screen off when inactive for Never.  Then I changed lock to OFF.  So now I do not see this issue, and do not need to reboot the machine every time I step away.

Comment: I'll experiment with this and will let you know